# Using rpc/jsonrpc in App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm confused reading "rpc" and "rpc/jsonrpc" code and docs. We won't listen to a port to serve RPC requests on App Engine, I mean, we won't "start a server", so how it should work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered by Brad Fitzpatrick on [google-appengine-go mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-go/browse_thread/thread/b90d1cbf49bd8f41):

> Basically, you can't.  That's only the first problem you'll hit.  The 
>   second major problem you'll find is that you can't get at the
>   *http.Request  to get an appengine.Context to do anything useful with App Engine in your  RPC handler.